# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to set up a PostgreSQL server using the instructions found on [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL). I installed the package via `apt-get install postgresql` and now I'm on the step:

`sudo -u postgres psql postgres`

which gives the error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I'm guessing the server isn't running but I'm not sure how to start it. Any tips would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Running `service postgresql status` doesn't output anything, even after `sudo service postgresql start`.

**UPDATE #2**: Running `ps auxw | grep post` doesn't turn up anything either, so I'm guessing the server daemon isn't running.

Comment: When you ran `apt-get install postgresql`, did you check that the installation actually was successful?  Please report the output of `apt-cache policy postgresql postgresql-9.1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check what database clusters are currently created:

```
pg_lsclusters
```

If there is one, but it's not running, then start it (substituting the version and name):

```
sudo pg_ctlcluster x.y name start
```

If there isn't one, create one and have it started:

```
sudo pg_createcluster --start x.y name
```

Normally, this should have happened automatically when you install the package.  So either something happened during package installation, or the package was already installed and someone had already messed around with the things I show above.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add that if anybody encounters this question but the postgresql server will start the service but not the main cluster fails to initialize then there is an error inside your pg_hba.conf file.

I had to delete every entry except the default ones to get the server to boot the service correctly again.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing a /32 on the end of an IP address I was attempting to whitelist.