# Postgresql server is not listening

Tags: postgresql

I know this question has asked many times, but non of those answers worked for me.

The problem is, when I run "psql", I get the message

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I run "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql status”, it says service is running,

```
postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor     preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-07-10 10:51:05 +0530; 22s ago
Process: 3219 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3219 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

But when I run “sudo lsof -i :5432” and “netstat -nltp | grep 5432” and “sudo netstat -lp --protocol=unix | grep postgres”, I gets an empty output.

Content of /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf is,

```
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Content of /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

```
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf'
port = 5432    
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Finally, I uninstalled postgres using “sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql* command and reinstalled using “apt-get install postgresql-9.5”, but the result is same.

Thank you

Comment: In `pg_hba`, change `peer` to `trust` and restart the server. `peer` only works if your Ubuntu user name matches the database user name. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, I did that change just now, but no any difference. I think for some reason postgresql is not listening at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could find an answer to solve my problem in here. [Cannot connect to PostgreSQL server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389459/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-server?rq=1). The issue was pg cluster wasn't initiating.

1. `sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.5 main start` - will tell whether cluster is running
2. Then if it gives any errors you can view them using `journalctl -xe`
3. It shown me the error as `DETAIL: File must have permissions u=rw (0600) or less if owned by the database user, or permissions u=rw,g=r (0640) or less if owned by root`. Then Once I changed the permission of the private key file, problem solved